# Issue with returning output from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Following is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [aaa].[sp_getabc] (                
      @fromdate smalldatetime,                
@todate smalldatetime)                


AS                
BEGIN                
SET NOCOUNT ON;                


declare @tmp1 as int  
declare @tmp2 as int  
declare @sum as int  
declare @tmp3 as int  
select @tmp1 = (select count(*) as decdbo from abc where AppID IN (108,104,113,110,218,171) and Status IN ('T','L') and calldate between  @fromdate and  @todate)  
select @tmp2 = (select count(*) as decauto from abc where AppID IN (278,283) and Status IN ('T','L') and calldate between  @fromdate and  @todate)  

select @sum = @tmp1 + @tmp2  

select @tmp3 = (select SUM(Duration)/60 as DecemberLastWeek from abc where dnis = '6503533019' and calldate between  @fromdate and  @todate)  

select @tmp3 as Duration , @sum as Transcriptions , @sum/@tmp3 as TransPerMin   


END
```

When i execute the statements not as stored procedure i get correct values whereas when i run the stored procedure i get nothing NULL in @tmp3 and @sum/@tmp3 whereas @sum also has wrong value . Where does the problem lie . Thank You

Comment: what are the variable you want to return?

Comment: When you say that you get correct values when you execute the statements, can you show us how do you give values to the variables `@fromdate` and `@todate`?

Comment: select count(*)  from abc where AppID IN (108,104,113,110,218,171) and Status IN ('T','L') and calldate between  '20121201' and '20121231'
    select count(*) as decauto from abc where AppID IN (278,283) and Status IN ('T','L') and calldate between  '20121201' and '20121231'

Comment: and when i execute sp i do like exec [autoivr].[sp_abc] '20120822','20121231'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem was that my stored procedure was in autoivr but the table i wanted to access was in dbo and i was not writing dbo with table name .

Answer (score 0):

Check your `@fromdate` and `@todate` variables,they must be different(i.e format) for both cases

Comment: you can see in sp it is same and this is how i execute it exec [autoivr].[sp_abc] '20120822','20121231'

Comment: print value of each variable in Stored procedure and try to find out where is it going wrong,i see there is some problem occurring in calculations.